# How to measure complete all-in performance of DOM changes?

Tags: html, performance, dom, svg

I've found lots of information about measuring load time for pages and quite a bit about profiling FPS performance of interactive applications, but this is something slightly different than that.

Say I have a chart rendered in SVG and every click I make causes the chart to render slightly differently.  I want to get a sense of the complete time elapsed between the click and the point in time that the pixels on the screen actually change.  Is there a way to do this?

Measuring the Javascript time is straight forward but that doesn't take into consideration any of the time the browser spends doing any layout, flow, paint, etc.

I know that Chrome timeline view shows a ton of good information about this, which is great for digging into issues but not so great for taking measurements because the tool itself affects performance and, more importantly, it's Chrome only. I was hoping there was a browser independent technique that might work.  Something akin to how the Navigation Performance API works for page load times.

Comment: Won't be implemented for privacy reasons, e.g. you might be able to figure out visited link state by timing the difference between rendering times.

Comment: Not sure about that, but at any rate it wouldn't be for use in production.  I wonder if I can achieve this by timing the interval between 2 requestAnimationFrame calls?  Kick of the code to change the DOM in one animation frame and time how long it takes for the second animation frame to be invoked.  The question is whether the browser will complete all of its work including painting before invoking the second call...

Answer (score 0):

you may consider using capturing hdmi capturing hardware  (just google for it) or a high speed camera to create a video, which could be analyzed offline.
http://www.webpagetest.org/ supports capturing using software only, but I guess it would be too slow for what you want to measure.